# How to decode a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, actionscript, utf-8, url-encoding

I'm trying to send a request from ActionScript to PHP, and it works, except for the utf-8 characters. My actionscript does something like this:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
```

and the PHP end receives the URL and processes it (i.e. inserts data to MySQL) like this:

```
    $text = @$_GET['text'];
    $text = urldecode($text);
    $pdo->query("INSERT INTO mytable(thetext) VALUES ('$text')");
```

Now, when the variable URL in ActionScript is this:

```
http://localhost/my_test_script.php?action=insert&text=non_utf_characters
```

I see the value `"non_utf_characters"` inserted correctly in MySQL Table.

But when the url is this:

```
http://localhost/my_test_script.php?action=insert&text=utf_characters_like_%C5%9E%C3%87%C3%96
```

It should be able to insert `"utf_characters_like_ŞÇÖ"`,

but it only inserts `"utf_characters_like_"`

So what should I do for php to recognize these characters from the URL?

**What I've tried :**

1. As you see in the php code, I've tried `urldecode()`
2. I've tried `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');`
3. I've saved all files as UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: If you're using PDO, please [use it correctly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or you lose [all the security benefits](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @Blazemonger you are right, this method is vulnerable to attacks, this is only the test phase, I will do that when the application is ready for visitors. Thanks !

Comment: Always better to do it in the first place -- one less thing to forget later.

Comment: Why do you use `urldecode`? If you're grabbing something from `$_GET`, it should have that done already.

Comment: [This question appears to be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590030/python-non-ascii-characters)

Comment: Also check the discussion on urldecode over at PHP.net. Lots of people have written functions to overcome its lack of unicode awareness. One of those might be what you want. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Thank you guys, for your help! I spotted the problem, it was basically I have forgot to encode the text, so I was writing the URL (in ActionScript) as '&text=utf_characters_like_ŞÇÖ' So there is no problem now, except prepared statements :)

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer and accept it? This will make it easier for others to recognize this post as a solved issue.

Comment: @RST you are right, but my problem was really only a typo. So I don't have a "solution".